# Symfony app writing config files to tmp directory

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, tmp

I've inherited an old Symfony app (Symfony 1.4) and had to migrate it to a new server. I have no experience with Symfony, but the migration went well and everything works fine except one thing; the new server's admin(s) complain about the app writing files to /tmp directory every minute:

Partial sample output from admins:

```
-rw-------  1 www-data  www-data      17133 Dec 18 14:45 config_routing.yml.php4VSPbj
-rw-------  1 www-data  www-data      17133 Dec 18 14:47 config_routing.yml.php8ZZlxn
-rw-------  1 www-data  www-data      17133 Dec 18 14:38 config_routing.yml.php9NH03d
-rw-------  1 www-data  www-data      17133 Dec 18 14:38 config_routing.yml.phpGA9YrM
-rw-------  1 www-data  www-data      17133 Dec 18 14:45 config_routing.yml.phpO9fYz5
-rw-------  1 www-data  www-data      17133 Dec 18 14:47 config_routing.yml.phpOiXAYC
-rw-------  1 www-data  www-data      17133 Dec 18 14:43 config_routing.yml.phpptNyFw
```

and these files as well:

config_settings.yml.php, config_databases.yml.php, config_autoload.yml.php.

I've made sure debugging is disabled in prod environment, but this still happens. Does anyone have any clue to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the applications cache directory does not exists, `tempnam()` function used by `sfConfigCache` class then defaults to using system temp directory.

The default location is `./cache`, create it and make it writable by apache.

To understand what is happening, snippets from [sfConfigCache](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine-website/blob/master/lib/vendor/symfony/config/sfConfigCache.class.php#L333) class:

Line 344: `$tmpFile = tempnam(dirname($cache), basename($cache));`
Here the `/tmp/config_routing.yml.php*` files are created, to be renamed or copied few lines later:

```
if (!@rename($tmpFile, $cache))
{
  if (copy($tmpFile, $cache))
  {
    unlink($tmpFile);
  }
}
```

Obviously, both rename and copy failed.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony creates cached versions of yml config files so it doesn't have to re-parse them on every request. This happens in both development and production.

The easiest way to prevent those errors is to enable write permissions for the Apache www-data user (or whatever Apache is running under). e.g.:

`sudo chmod 775 /tmp`

Alternatively you disable caching in the settings.yml file by adding/modifying the following lines:

`prod:
  .settings:
    cache: false`

This may also need to be done in the config file of your apps if they override the system default. For example in the file `apps/frontend/config/settings.yml`

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue where there are lots of files some.classes.phpRT8i4j5 filled up the /tmp directory.

What I found out is different but still hope that it will help someone. My case is because I put log level to debug in production which is not a good practice obviously. so I had to put it back to error instead here is example and the file location is app/config/config_prod.yml -> change level: debug to error in the green cursor box. Good luck!

[image]